# Flutter esys_flutter_share plugin works only on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, android-intent

I'm using the esys_flutter_share plugin on my flutter app. It works perfectly well on my simulator and test devices, but I cannot share anything on real/production devices.

I've tried everything. I'm not sure where to look now.

What am I missing?

On the test/simulators, the share window pops up giving me options to share my file to Facebook, email, instagram, etc. But this window doesn't show in real devices.

Has anyone here had this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason for using an unofficial plugin instead of the official [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) plugin? `esys_flutter_share` might need extra config on android that wasn't documented. I don't know anything about it however.

Comment: I tried the official Share plugin, but this seems only to be able to share text.. not images.